# webBrowser.Navigate synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, browser

i want to call webBrowser.Navigate(string urlString) synchronously where webBrowser is windows forms control. I do this in such way

```
...
private delegate void NavigateDelegate(string s);
...
private void Function()
{
    NavigateDelegate navigateDelegate = 
        new NavigateDelegate(this.webBrowser1.Navigate);
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = 
        navigateDelegate.BeginInvoke("http://google.com", null, null);

    while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Operation has completed !");
}
```

but message is never shoved. WHY this code doesn't work properly?

Comment: You don't need to use delegate - webbrowser.Navigate is asynchronous method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigate.aspx

Comment: i knew that this method is asynchronous. And i wanted remake it syncronously and i thought this code would help me ...

Comment: delegate.BeginInvoke is asynchronous method. Your code runs asynchronous method asynchronous: two times asynchronous. So, it's not what you want to do at all.

Comment: you are completely right ! thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather use this to retrieve the page *syncronously*:

```
this.webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
this.webBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com");

private void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Operation has completed !");
}
```

Comment: thank you Teoman for very quick answer, but i am rather interested WHY my code does not work, not how can I implement this !

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you're trying to use the Navigate function asyncronously. To get the result you will need to use EndInvoke but if sync way of calling this is what you want, above code snippet is the way to go.

Comment: Yes but not in the sense of using BeginInvoke or a separate thread. Main thread can easily be blocked via sleeping during documentloading event.

Comment: If you write in answer Synchronous and mean, that this is asynchronous (because synchronous can block main thread), this may lead reader to misunderstanding. Btw, I am pretty sure, that internally Navigate also uses separate thread.

Answer (score 5):

Not the best way, but you can use this...

```
while (this.webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
     Application.DoEvents();
     Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```