# While loop interrupting webBrowser navigation?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a method `TestScenarios()` which is supposed to loop through a database of scenarios, and for each item in the database, navigate to a specified url, take a screenshot, and change some values.

The line I'm having trouble with is the `webBrowser1.Navigate(Url);` line.  When I step through the function, `Url` has the value of `http://google.com`, and yet the web control never displays.

Instead, it just says something along the lines of "Navigation has been canceled," which leads me to believe that something is interrupting the `Navigate()` function from completing.

Furthermore, if I stick a line `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");` outside of the while loop, it shows the web control, which means that the `webBrowser` controls seems to be functioning properly.

Basically I just need some help with direction.  Code is below.

```
public void TestScenarios()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Scenarios WHERE MarkedForDeletion!='1'", conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Store scenario information
                    int Id = (int) reader["ScenarioID"];
                    string Data = reader["ScenarioData"].ToString();
                    string Url = reader["ScenarioURL"].ToString();

                    // Navigate to webBrowser
                    webBrowser1.Navigate(Url);

                    // Do test
                    int HasSucceeded = 0;
                    if (Url == "http://bing.com")
                    {
                        HasSucceeded = 1;
                    }

                    // Take Screenshot
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
                    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                    Byte[] screenshot = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[]));

                    // Insert results
                    InsertResults(Id, HasSucceeded, screenshot);

                    // Delete scenario
                    // DeleteScenario(Id);

                    // Mark scenario for deletion
                    MarkScenario(Id);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigate is Asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Browser.navigate takes place asynchronously. So it is navigating (making the page request) then immediately moving on to the next call `if url== "http://bing.com"`

You want this to be asynchrounous, so you need to setup an event handler to handle the navigation completed event

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162381/webbrowser-navigate-synchronously) has some information for you on how you would apply that