# How can I load a Website in Forms and Alter the Page loaded, load another Page by one Button only

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I do that becouse I want to do multiple things, and then load the next site. All that by only one button. My code looks like this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://THE SITE I WANT");
            HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("id").Equals("xxxxx"))
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

//And now it should load the next Page but its not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Navigate()` is asynchronous. You want to wait for the `Navigated`, `DocumentCompleted` or similar event to fire, *then* start parsing the results, and only then can you navigate again.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162381/webbrowser-navigate-synchronously).

Comment: I did link to a question with answers on how it can be done. You need event handlers.